# How to resolve Stored XSS issue in salesforce security scan result?

Tags: stored-xss

Below is the example code for this issue

```
<apex:OutputText value="{!question.selectedVal}" escape="false"/>
```

We cannot remove the escape false because we need to show the HTML content. 
How to pass security review for this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to resolve this issue you will need to change the code as below

```
<apex:OutputText value="{!question.selectedVal}" escape="false"/>
```

To

```
<apex:outputPanel id="richtextelement"/>
<script>var richtextelement = document.getElementById('{!$Component.richtextelement}'); $(richtextelement).html($('<div/>').html('{!JSENCODE(question.selectedVal)}').html());</script>
```

Comment: You will need to include jquery refresh to work this code.